# different background color in columns, same page

Tags: html, css, wordpress, containers, background-color

I am pretty new to wordpress but I am trying to create 2 columns (I am using the Easy Columns plugin) and I want the two columns on the same page to have different background colors. So on the left column I will have a few images then some text then some more images and the right the same. I have the images and the text done in wordpress but I can't figure out how to add the background color to just the columns. FYI, there is a white background on the page, the left column has RGB(201,159,102), and the right column has RGB(202,202,194). I tried creating a container in wordpress with:

```
<div id="column1">
```

and also adding:

```
/* column 1 */
column1.div{
    background-color: rgb(201, 159, 102);
}
```

to the style.css. Also I am using the Grande Green child theme, and I am not sure if I should change the Grande Green style.css or the Grande style.css.

Comment: So do I change the child theme style.css or the parent?

Answer (score 3):

If you have id "column1" don't add "column1.div" to css, but

```
#column1 {
    background: rgb(201, 159, 102);
}
```

with id's there is no reason to add div to it, much cleaner

Comment: Also note that appending or prepending the unnecessary 'div' is slower to process albeit it's a tiny amount but can all add up.

Comment: ok thanks, I changed my css to that but when I hit "preview page" no change occurs. I am editing the style.css in the child theme I am wondering if the page is even using that style sheet or what. Do I need to add it to the parent theme?

Comment: Have you added: <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"> to your html head tag?
It also depends how you have organised your folders, you have to target them correctly. Have you ever seen any css styling on your html?

Comment: Thanks for the responses, in all of our wordpress pages I can't find any reference to any style sheets. They only link to photos or  something like <div class="one_fourth"> which is just an alignment thing like 25% of the page. Should I be using something like page.id in the files?

Answer (score 0):

Changing your code will be a good start. Do something like below. You can ID the columns and then set different background colors for each.

```
    /* column 1 */

    #column1 {
        background-color: green; /* You desired color */
     }


     /* column 2 */

       #column2 {
            background-color: yellow; /* You desired color */
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more semantic for the browser.

```
div#column:first-child{
  background-color: blue;
}

div#column:last-child{
  background-color: green;
}
```